# parrot sec version 5.3 .ova file for virtualbox default password is NOT toor. what is it?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, passwords

I properly imported the Parrot Security version .ova file into virtualbox, but when I sudo for an update, and it asks me for the password, default password root does not work.  WHY? Has it changed?  How can I (or anyone) find out this information?

Comment: Where did you get this `.ova` file?

Comment: `sudo` usually does *not* ask for root's password, but the user's password instead. Are you sure you should be using `sudo`?

Comment: If need be, you can download the Parrot ISO and build your own machine. I have a Parrot machine by doing that and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The sudo password for the VM image is "parrot"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The password for a custom user in parrot 5.3 is toor ,,but on root user you have to set it first using 'sudo passwd root' then try login in with your password as root.